# Выборка чистого текста из web-страницы без посторонних библиотек на Python

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть задача взять веб-страницу (например, любую из lenta.ru), убрать всё лишнее и оставить только текст. 
Видимо между тегами `<p>` и `</p>`. Далее готовый текст сохранить в текстовом файле.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

site = 'https://lenta.ru/news/2019/10/17/competition/'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

for link in soup.find_all('p', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

Пересмотрел много примеров работы с `request` и `BeautifulSoup`, но общего понимания нет.

Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: А каким образом можно реализовать тоже самое, но чтобы парсер любой сайт мог обрабатывать. Убирать лишние теги, брать только полезный текст и сохранять его в файл.

Comment: Что такое полезный текст? Как Вы отличаете полезный текст от другого?

Comment: И почему у Вас в вопросе фигурирует *"без сторонних библиотек"*, но Вы используете `BeautifulSoup` и `requests`?

Comment: Под полезным имею ввиду, например саму статью с заголовком, за вычетом ссылок, спамов, и т.д. А про сторонние не так выразился... Имел ввиду, не используя готовые скраперы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # для разбора html     # pip install bs4
import requests                 # для доступа к сайту  # pip install import requests


class Content:
    def __init__(self, url, title, body):
        self.url   = url
        self.title = title
        self.body  = body


def get_page(url):
    req = requests.get(url)

    if req.status_code == 200:
        return BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    return None 

def news_form_lenta(url):
    bs = get_page(url)
    if bs is None:
        return bs
    titleBs = bs.find("title")
    if titleBs:
        title = titleBs.text
    else: title = ' '
    lines = bs.find_all("p")
    body  = '\n'.join([line.text.strip() for line in lines])
    return Content(url, title, body)


#content = news_form_lenta('https://lenta.ru/news/2019/10/17/competition/')
# или
content = news_form_lenta('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036579/Выборка-чистого-текста-из-web-страницы-без-посторонних-библиотек-на-python/1036592?noredirect=1#comment1766495_1036592')


if content is None:
    print("Ошибка!")
else:
    with open('fileOutput.txt', 'w') as f:
        print("Заголовок: {}".format(content.title), file=f)
        print("\nАдрес    : {}\n".format(content.url), file=f)
        print(content.body, file=f)
```

---

**fileOutput.txt**

```
Заголовок: html - Выборка чистого текста из web-страницы без посторонних библиотек на python - Stack Overflow на русском

Адрес    : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036579/Выборка-чистого-текста-из-web-страницы-без-посторонних-библиотек-на-python/1036592?noredirect=1#comment1766495_1036592

Используя наш сайт, вы подтверждаете, что прочитали и поняли политику о куки, политику конфиденциальности и пользовательское соглашение.
Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для программистов. Присоединяйтесь! Регистрация займёт не больше минуты.
Подскажите, пожалуйста... Есть задача взять веб-страницу (например, любую из lenta.ru), убрать всё лишнее и оставить только текст. Видимо между тегами <p> и </p>. Далее готовый текст сохранить в текстовом файле.
Пересмотрел много примеров работы с request и BeautifulSoup, но общего понимания нет. Каким образом это можно реализовать?
Попробуйте так:
Спасибо за ваш ответ на Stack Overflow на русском!
Но избегайте …
Также, обратите внимание на заметку в справочном центре о том, как писать ответы.
Необходима, но никому не показывается
Необходима, но никому не показывается
Нажимая на кнопку «Отправить ответ», вы соглашаетесь с нашими пользовательским соглашением, политикой конфиденциальности и политикой о куки
Для подписки на ленту скопируйте и вставьте эту ссылку в вашу программу для чтения RSS.
дизайн сайта / логотип © 2019 Stack Exchange Inc; пользовательское содержимое попадает под действие лицензии cc by-sa 4.0 с указанием ссылки на источник.

                    rev 2019.10.18.35213
```

Comment: @Артур я обновил ответ, попробуйте.

Comment: Большое спасибо) Изучаю ООП как раз... Пытаюсь понять, зачем же нужно все оборачивать в классы )

Comment: @Артур если мой ответ решил вашу  проблему, не забудьте отметить его как правильный.